# Swift 3: Select an Array based on a dictionary

Tags: swift

I have a popover view controller that contains a table view with a list of options, similar to a drop down selection list.  This table view is populated dynamically, depending on which "select" button the user hits on the parent view controller.  I have several Arrays built for the various option sets to populate the TVC.  How can I use the fieldIndex dictionary to automatically set the array to be used as the TVC datasource for the popover?

```
class MyWidget : NSObject {

  var fieldIndex : [Int:String] = [
        0 : "make",
        1 : "model",
        2 : "year"
  ]

  var make = String()
  var model = String()
  var year = String()   
}

var makes = ["Acme", "Contoso", "Tradewinds"]
var models = ["Model1", "Model2", "Model3"]
var years = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
```

[image: Parent View Controller]

Comment: what about `var fieldIndex: [Int: [String]]`

Comment: Why are you subclassing NSObject ? If you are not gonna make your class NSCoding compliant you shouldn't.

Comment: Why don't you add this logic directly in your class, and subclassing NSObject?

Comment: BTW a struct would be more appropriate

Comment: @LeoDabus, I use setValueForKey on this class all the time.  Doesn't that require NSObject?

Comment: @LeoDabus, I've never used a struct, please explain.

Comment: @GED125 sorry I can't really understand your goal but looks like you should create a Automobile struct with make, model and year properties and add 3 array of those struc properties to your class. If you need an ordered collection you should use an array instead of a dictionary for your field index

Comment: @GED125 Question: Are you trying to populate your popover  tableview with  different models depending on the make selected by the user and than the years depending on the model selected ? Does the user have to select them in this specific order (Make, Model, Year)?

Comment: @LeoDabus, I've added a picture of the parent view controller.  Basically when a user hits the select for a given field, I want the PopOver Controller to be populated by an array of those types.  For example if someone clicks the select button next to the "Phone Button Template" text box, I want the PopOver controller to list the available templates (which are constantly changing by the way).  I have this working with a switch now, switching off the IndexPath of the cell that contained the button that was clicked.  This works, but I'm looking for something more scalable.  100's of fields.

Comment: @GED125 update your question with your actual code

Comment: @LeoDabus, I'm pretty close to a solution, I'll post when I do.  Right now it's a switch, so it doesn't really apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create dictionary of type `Int: [String]`

```
class MyWidget : NSObject { 
// empty fieldData dictionary of type Int: [String]
var fieldData = [Int: [String]]()

}
```

// add data like this

```
fieldData[0] = ["Acme", "Contoso", "Tradewinds"]
fieldData[1] = ["Model1", "Model2", "Model3"]
fieldData[2] = ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
```

// get data like this

```
let makeArray = fieldData[0]
```

Comment: Thanks Sahil, I will give this a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I might approach it this way.

```
enum Attribute {
    case make, model, year

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .make:     return "Make"
        case .model:    return "Model"
        case .year:     return "Year"
        }
    }

    var allAttribtues: [Attribute] {
        return [.make, .model, .year]
    }
}

class AttributeDataSource {
    func options(for attribute: Attribute) -> [String] {
        switch attribute {
        case .make:     return ["Acme", "Contoso", "Tradewinds"]
        case .model:    return ["Model1", "Model2", "Model3"]
        case .year:     return ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
        }
    }
}

let dataSource = AttributeDataSource()

dataSource.options(for: .make)  // -> ["Acme", "Contoso", "Tradewinds"]
dataSource.options(for: .model) // -> ["Model1", "Model2", "Model3"]
dataSource.options(for: .year)  // -> ["2015", "2016", "2017"]
```

Don't hesitate to make first-class models for your data structures. Most of the time it will make things much more clear.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am currently doing this with a switch, but was hoping to avoid it, as there are literally hundreds of fields I'll be working with.  That's why I wanted to use a dictionary to lookup the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `NSObject` is to add this logic into a `function` directly in your code:

```
func getArray(_ positionInDictionary: Int) -> [String]{
    var fieldData: [Int:[String]] = [0 : ["Choice 01", "Choice 02", "Choice 03"], 1 : ["Choice 11","Choice 12","Choice 13"]]
    if let str = fieldData[positionInDictionary]{
        return str
    }
    else{ return []}
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var dataArray = getArray(1)
```

Also, this is IMO the simplest and fastest solution, and you can retrieve your dictionary from wherever you want.